# TypeError: 'Namespace' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, arguments

I assigned a list data ("patch data") as an option to arguments like below:

```
args = run_model_opts.RunModelOpts().parse()
log = logger.Logger(args)
      
for c in wtd_patch_list_final:
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        args["patch_data"] = c
        torch.manual_seed(args.seed)
        main(args)
```

To the argument I added "patch data" in another script for model options:

```
self.parser.add_argument('--patch_data', default="", type=list) #edited
```

However, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "make_relighted_dataset.py", line 84, in <module>
    args["patch_data"] = c
TypeError: 'Namespace' object does not support item assignment
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Why are you trying this in the first place? Did you mean `args.patch_data = c`?